# Expected Hamming Distance is equal to spherical distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $A=[a_1,\ldots,a_n]\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix with independent entries, each standard normal distributed. In a paper, it is claimed that for unit vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it holds:
$$\mathbb{E}[d_{H}(\text{sign}(Ax),\text{sign}(Ay))]=d_{S}(x,y),$$ where $d_{H}$ denotes the normalized Hamming distance, and $d_{S}$ denotes the spherical distance.

I don't know how to proof this statement. I would be glad for some hints.

I know that it holds: 
$$d_{H}(\text{sign}(Ax),\text{sign}(Ay))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{\mathcal{A}_{i}},$$
where $I$ denotes the indicator function, and $\mathcal{A}_{i}$ denotes the event $\left\{\text{sign}(\langle a_i,x\rangle)\neq\text{sign}(\langle a_i,y\rangle) \right\}$, or equivalently $\left\{\langle a_i,x\rangle \langle a_i,y\rangle<0 \right\}$. Thus one need perhaps to compute the probability of those events. Furthermore, i know that the RVs $\langle a_i,x\rangle$ and $\langle a_i,x\rangle$ are each standard normal distributed, and are jointly gaussian with correlation $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Thank you for your help in advance.